# How to write a method for a defined algebraic data type using selfwritten fold-method in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, abstract-class, fold

I have a problem with an algebraic data type Network. This is our assignment for this week and I've spent the whole weekend trying to find an answer, but I could not manage to wrap my head around it. 
Our task was it, to write a fold-method for that data type and after that we should create some methods using that fold-method. So this is the datatype as it was given to us:

```
sealed abstract class Network
case object Empty extends Network
case object Internet extends Network
case class Switch(name: String, n1: Network, n2: Network, n3: Network = Empty) extends Network
case class Router(name: String, in: Network, out: Network) extends Network
case class Pc(name: String, harddriveCapacity: Int) extends Network
```

And this is the fold-method I came up with:

```
def foldNetwork0[A](fSwitch: (String, A, A, A) => A,
              fRouter: (String, A, A) => A,
              fPc: (String, Int) => A,
              fInternet: A, 
              fEmpty: A) (darknet: Network): A =
darknet match {
  case Switch(name, n1, n2, n3) => {
    val n1res = foldNetwork0(fSwitch, fRouter, fPc, fInternet, fEmpty)(n1)
    val n2res = foldNetwork0(fSwitch, fRouter, fPc, fInternet, fEmpty)(n2)
    val n3res = foldNetwork0(fSwitch, fRouter, fPc, fInternet, fEmpty)(n3)
    fSwitch(name, n1res, n2res, n3res)
  }
  case Router(name, in, out) => {
    val inres = foldNetwork0(fSwitch, fRouter, fPc, fInternet, fEmpty)(in)
    val outres = foldNetwork0(fSwitch, fRouter, fPc, fInternet, fEmpty)(out)
    fRouter(name, inres, outres)
  }
  case Pc(name, hdCap) => fPc(name, hdCap)
  case Internet => fInternet
  case Empty => fEmpty
}
```

They also gave us an example of a Network-structure:

```
val network = Router("Fritzbox",
  Internet,
  Switch("Switch",
    Pc("Gamerkiste", 500),
    Pc("Mediensklave", 4000),
    Switch("YetAnotherSwitch",
      Pc("Hex", 5),
      Pc("HAL9000", Int.MaxValue)
    )
  )
)
```

Well, the second task was to write a method countCables, which counts the cables between the cases of the Network. And this is the first one that didn't throw a bunch of warnings and errors, but it does not count the cables. To the case object Empty is no connection with a cable, so there is no adding needed. This is the method:

```
def countCables0[A](net: Network, x: Int): Int = {
  foldNetwork0(
    (_: String, n1: Int, n2: Int, n3: Int) => x + n1 + n2 + n3,
    (_: String, n1: Int, n2: Int) => x + n1 + n2,
    (_: String, _: Int) => x+1, x+1, x+1)(net)
  println("There are "+x+" cable in the network.")
  x
}
```

But it returns zero all the time. I don't know if my fold-method is wrong or if the countCables method is wrong, but it doesn't work. 
So I figured that maybe some of you guys can give me a hint on how to proceed.

Thanks in advance 
TheGBox

Comment: So... have you tried stepping through `countCables` for a simple network to check it returns the right value and if not where it goes wrong? This seems something solvable by straightforward debugging rather than asking others to find the error in your assignment's answer?

Comment: But it's at least in part because you don't do anything in `countCables0` with the value returned by `foldNetwork0`. Instead, you just print (and return) the initial value of x that `countCables0` was called with! There are other errors too  but I'll let you work those  out (consider what `x` is referring to in the functions you're passing to `foldNetwork0`)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I've never intended to let someone do the work for me. But it's just demotivating if you can't get the result that you want to get. I haven't tried another network for that countCables method, but I made some other abstract classes and implemented some methods on them and it worked great. I did try to add something to x as you can see, but I guess I have to rethink that part again. But thanks for the advice. :)

Comment: Try a really simple network first, and learn how to step through a program  in the debugger. You're in good company:  "As soon as we started programming, we found to our surprise that it wasn’t as easy to get programs right as we had thought. Debugging had to be discovered. I can remember the exact instant when I realized that a large part of my life from then on was going to be spent in finding mistakes in my own programs.

        — Maurice Wilkes discovers debugging, 1949"